# Calculating the number of times an if statement is executed

Tags: algorithm

This code counts how many integer triples  sum to 0: The full code is [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/ThreeSum.java.html).

```
initialise an int array of length n
int cnt = 0 // cnt is the number of triples that sum to 0
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
        for (int k = j+1; k < n; k++) {
            if (array[i]+array[j]+array[k] == 0) {
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, from the book Algorithms by Robert Sedgewick, I read that:

- The initialisation of `cnt` to `0` is executed exactly once.
- `cnt++` is executed from 0 to the number of times a triple is found.
- The if statement is executed `n(n-1)(n-2)/6` times.

I've done some experiments and all of them are true. But I completely don't know how they calculate the number of times the if statement got executed.
I'm not sure, but I think that:

- `n` means from `i to n`
- `(n-1)` means from `i+1` to `n`
- `(n-2)` means from `j+1` to `n`
- `/6` I don't know what's this for.

Can anyone explain how to calculate this?

Comment: The partial expression /6 means division by 6. See binomial coefficients. Any way to choose 3 elements from {0,...,n-1} corresponds to one choice of i, j, and k.

Comment: You cannot attribute the formula to the loop variables (i.e `(n-1)` does not mean `i+1 to n` or `(n-2)` does not mean `(j+1) to n`) , Think of formula as a result of summation, Look at the link @amit posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's sum of sums.

1. The inner loop is executed `n-j-1` times each time it is being reached
2. The middle loop is executed `n-i-1` times each time it is being reached
3. The outer loop is executed `n` times.

[Sum all of these](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28+sum+%28+n-j-1+%2C+i+%3C+j+%3C+n%29+%2C+0+%3C%3D+i+%3C+n%29) and you get total number of times the `cnt++` is invoked.

---

Note that the number of times the middle loop is executed each time is NOT `n-1`, it is `n-i-1`, where `i` is the index of the outer loop. Similarly for middle loop.

The `/6` factor is coming from taking it into account in the summation formula.

Comment: ok, but I still don't understand why we divide by 6. How did we get 6?

Comment: @morbidCode Look edit. Think is the middle loop does NOT run `n-1` times, it run `n-i-1` times. You then sum them all up in a sum of sums formula, to get the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This can be viewed as a [combinatorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) problem. To pick 3 unique items from `n` items (`k=3` in the linked article) gives `n!/(n-3)! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)` possibilities. However, in the code the order of the 3 items doesn't matter. For each combination of 3 items, there are `3! = 6` permutations. So we need to divide by 6 to get only orderless possibilities. So we get `n!/(3!(n-3)!) = n(n-1)(n-2)/6`

Comment: Your last paragraph seems quite confused. In the for loop, the variables i, j, and k are restricted to be less than n, so there is no index-out-of-bounds exception.

Comment: The division by 6 comes from i<j<k, which you can see from the initial values in the loops not the upper limits.

Comment: If there were no upper limits but only initial values, then the complexity would be simply `n(n-1)(n-2)`, no? edit: Ah no, I see now, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

First loop executes for N times (0 to N-1)

Time to execute outer loop is:

```
Fi(0) + Fi(1) + Fi(2)...Fi(N-1)
```

When `i` is `0`, middle loop executes `N-1` times (1 to N-1)
When `i` is `1`, middle loop executes `N-2` times (2 to N-1)
...

Time to execute middle loop is:

```
Fi(0) = Fj(1) + Fj(2) ... Fj(N-1)
Fi(1) = Fj(2) + Fj(3) ... Fj(N-1)
Fi(0) + Fi(1) + Fi(2)...Fi(N-1) = Fj(1) + 2Fj(2) + ... (N-1)Fj(N-1)
```

Now come to the inner most loop:

When `j` is `1`, inner loop executes `N-2` times (2 to N-2)
When `j` is `2`, inner loop executes `N-3` times (3 to N-2)
...

```
Fj(1) = Fk(2) + Fk(3) ... Fk(N-1) = 2 + 3 + ... N-1
Fj(2) = Fk(3) + Fk(4) ... Fk(N-1) = 3 + 4 + ... N-1
Fj(1) + 2Fj(2) + ... (N-1)Fj(N-1) = (2 + 3 + ... N-1) + (3 + 4 + ... N-1) ... (N-1)
  = 1 x 2 + 2 x 3 + 3 x 4 .... (N-2) x (N-1)
  = 1x1 + 2x2 + 3x3 + 4x4 .... (N-1)*(N-1) - (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + N-1)
  = (N-1) N (N+1) / 6 - N (N-1) / 2
  = N (N-1) ((N+1)/2 - 1/2)
  = N (N-1) (N-2) / 6
```

You may want to also check: Formula to calculate the sum of squares of [first N natural numbers](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalSquares.htm) and sum of [first N natural numbers](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumNaturalNumbers.htm).

---

Alternate explanation:

You are finding all pairs of triplets. This can be done in <sup>N</sup>C<sub>3</sub> ways. i.e. `(N) * (N-1) * (N-2) / (1 * 2 * 3)` ways.

Answer (score 1):

The basis of this formula comes from the sum of a progression:

```
1+2 = 3
1+2+3 = 6
1+2+3+4 = 10
```

There exists the Formula:

```
Sum(1..N) == N*(N+1)/2

1+2+3+4 = 4*5/2 = 10
```

With a recursive progression (like in this case) you get another formula for the sums.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, where i runs from 0 to n, j from i to n, k from j to n, the if statement is executed about n^3 / 6 times. To see why that is so, look at this code which will obviously execute the if statement just as often:

```
int cnt = 0 // cnt is the number of triples that sum to 0
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            if (j > i && k > j) {
                if (array[i]+array[j]+array[k] == 0) {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The inner loop now obviously executes n^3 times. The if statement is executed if i < j < k. We ignore the case that i == j or i == k or j == k. The three variables i, j and k could be sorted in six different orders (i < j < k, i < k < j, j < i < k etc.). Since each of these six different sorting orders happens equally often, about n^3 / 6 times we have the order i < j < k.